# asp.net c# Must declare the scalar variable error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm using query string at my project, every thing is will except this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@cAND".

this is my code:

```
            string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Mydb"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            searchKey.Text = Request.QueryString["n"];
            try
            {
                // Try to open the connection.
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand viewH = new SqlCommand();
                viewH.Connection = con;

                String sql = @"SELECT * FROM hotels ";


                if (Request.QueryString["n"] != "" && Request.QueryString["n"] != null)
                {
                    sql += "WHERE h_name LIKE '%' + @n + '%'";
                    viewH.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", Request.QueryString["n"]);
                }
                else
                    sql += "WHERE h_name LIKE '%%' ";                

                if (Request.QueryString["c"] != "" && Request.QueryString["c"] != null)
                {
                    sql += "AND h_country = @c";
                    viewH.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", Request.QueryString["c"]);
                }

                if (Request.QueryString["f"] != "" && Request.QueryString["f"] != null)
                {
                    sql += "AND h_price > @f";
                    viewH.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["f"]));
                }

                if (Request.QueryString["t"] != "" && Request.QueryString["t"] != null)
                {
                    sql += "AND h_price <@t";
                    viewH.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t", Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["t"]));
                }
                if (Request.QueryString["s"] != "" && Request.QueryString["s"] != null)
                {
                    sql += "AND h_stars = @s";
                    viewH.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s", Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["s"]));
                }

                viewH.CommandText = sql;          
                SqlDataReader data = viewH.ExecuteReader();

        htmlStr = new StringBuilder("");
                while (data.Read())
                {... etc ... }
```

error appears just when I use (s) query string at my website like

> example.com/hotels.aspx?c=sy&s=1

but if I use a this link:
example.com/hotels.aspx?s=1
no problems shown

Comment: Did you try debugging the program and looking at what the sql ended up being? If not, why are you even asking a question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be that when you construct `sql` string you do not add a space after `c`, so you concatenate it with the following `AND`?

Comment: No, it "could" not be that this is the problem. This is **definitively** the problem.

Comment: +1 `AND h_country = @cAND h_price > @f` clearly not valid SQL. Consider if some LINQ-to-SQL would work for you to avoid string concatenation to build SQL.

Comment: Thank you very much, it has been solved by adding space after @c